# How to add a css class to Choice field via XSL

Tags: 2010, xslt, css

Salvete!  I have a list with a Choice field called "Scope".  I want to add a class to that field using XSL, but I can't figure out how to get it to change.  I want all the items in that field to get my css class, but also keep the ms-vb2 class.  Here is my attempt:

I've gotten this far, but it doesn't seem to quite work.

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']" mode="Text_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <td class="ms-vb2">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">mycssclass</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Scope" />
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried this, too:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']" mode="Choice_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <td class="ms-vb2 RatingsCSStoken">{$thisNode/@Scope}</td>
</xsl:template>
```

Maybe I don't have the `mode` right?  I've tried everything.

I am using a custom xsl file in the _layouts directory, and using the match to make changes to any column with that fieldref name.

[two months later] I am still stuck on this.  Doesn't anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to define Custom Rendering for a [SPFieldChoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx) field in template for mode attribute should be used value **body**

In your case template would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <!-- Your custom rendering for choice field goes here --> 
</xsl:template>
```

Save your XSLT stylesheet in `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL`, using the following naming convention: `fldtypes_YourFieldTypeName.xsl`

---

But keep in mind, specified template is intended for rendering field. HTML table cell element (TD) that contains field element

```
<td class="ms-vb2">
```

is rendered in parent template `printTableCellEcbAllowed`. For more details see [Overview of XSLT List View Rendering System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604024.aspx).

So, in your case it would be better specify CSS class not in `TD`, but to HTML element used to render field itself, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <span class="RatingsCSStoken"><!-- Your custom rendering for choice field goes here --></span> 
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps,

Vadim